# Why are the "increment" and "decrement" operators not composable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, integer, operators, variable-assignment, increment

If I have a `var i : Int = 0`, then `i.inc().inc()` works just fine, i.e. `inc()` is composable with itself. Why then does `(i++)++` make Kotlin report the error "Variable expected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [The effect of computing the expression [`a++`] is](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#increments-and-decrements):
>
> - Store the initial value of a to a temporary storage a0.
> - Assign the result of a0.inc() to a.
> - Return a0 as the result of the expression.

So if you tried to use `i++` as `a` above to determine the meaning of `(i++)++`, it would translate to

```
val i1 = i++
i++ = i1.inc()
i1
```

Of course, `i++ = i1.inc()` doesn't make sense (never mind that it would also calculate `i++` twice).

Comment: So it seems that the answer boils down to the fact that `++` is not a pure function: it has a side-effect (an assignment). These small but unpleasant surprises make me appreciate functional programming even more. I'm curious whether Scala has fewer such surprises to offer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `inc()`, it returns a new Int and does nothing to the property or variable that held the original value. When you use it as an operator, it is interpreted as also setting the return value on the original property or variable. This cannot conceptually extend to using it as an operator on something that is not a variable or value.